# Why does Valgrind report "Invalid read of size 2"?

Tags: c

```
struct item
{
    int a;
};
int main()
{
    item *a = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
    item *b = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
    short *c = (short *)b;
    c += 3; 
    memcpy(a, c, sizeof(int));
    free(a);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) echo "Invalid read of size 2"? I think it should be size 4.

Example message from Valgrind:

```
==19134== Invalid read of size 2
==19134== at 0x4C2F7E0: memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14 (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19134== by 0x400625: main (main.cpp:19)
==19134== Address 0x51fd096 is 2 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==19134== at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==19134== by 0x4005FC: main (main.cpp:16)
```

Comment: What is `sizeof(int)` with your compiler?  Plausible values are 4 (probable) and 2 (less likely, by quite a margin).  Your code is invoking undefined behaviour; you are forcing `memcpy()` to access memory way outside the bounds of what was allocated to `b`. There's an element of "it doesn't matter what the size reported is; the code is invalid because it invokes undefined behaviour and therefore any behaviour is OK".  I assume the real code has `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <string.h>` in front.  Do you get any compilation warnings?

Comment: The statement c += 3 is advancing c by 6 bytes (assuming a short is 2 bytes). Perhaps the 4 byte block pointed to by b is located immediately after that pointed to by a, so you have 8 contiguous bytes. Then, memcpy is reading 2 bytes beyond the end of this block.

Comment: @RobJinman That was my initial thought but we actually really can't know that...undefined behavior is the right answer.  It very well could just be coincidence.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Boundaries aside, does casting `item*` to `short*` run afoul of [strict aliasing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)?  Would memcpy count as "dereferencing"?

Comment: @HostileFork: GCC 4.9.1 doesn't think so with `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror -fstrict-aliasing`.  Of course, I had to change the structure definition into a `typedef` (the code was originally compiled by a C++ compiler — hence the casts on the results of `malloc()`).  (See [GCC Manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) for information about warning options.)

Comment: Here are some refrence: value a 0x602010, value b 0x602030, value c 0x602036, sizeof(int) 4

Comment: Running your code (compiled for 64-bit on Ubuntu 14.04), `valgrind` reports what I'd expect: `==12694== Invalid read of size 4`
`==12694==    at 0x4004B0: main (string3.h:51)`
`==12694==  Address 0x51fd096 is 2 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd`
`==12694==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)`
`==12694==    by 0x4004AC: main (d79.c:12)`
Can you show the exact output you get from `valgrind`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler      ==19134== Invalid read of size 2
    ==19134==    at 0x4C2F7E0: memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14 (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==19134==    by 0x400625: main (main.cpp:19)
    ==19134==  Address 0x51fd096 is 2 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
    ==19134==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
    ==19134==    by 0x4005FC: main (main.cpp:16)

Comment: In future, please edit such information into the question where it can be formatted, rather than into a comment.  I had to put mine in a comment because it isn't part of the question you asked, but you should update your question with the extra info.  I've done it for you this time.

Comment: You Valgrind reports the same basic problem (reading 2 bytes after the end of a block of 4).  I don't have a good explanation for why it is a 2-byte read rather than a 4-byte read; I can only guess that for the combination of versions of GCC and GLIBC and Valgrind in 32-bit mode on your platform, the copy ends up being done as two 2-byte transfers, maybe influenced by the type of `c`, which is a `short *`.  I was not able to get a 32-bit compilation to work on my Ubuntu VM; there was a header missing.  One day, I'll work out why that is and fix it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks a lot. I have tried on another computer, it echo invalid read size 4 , but when I edit code and expand invalid read size, it always show Invalid read of size 8, which is not expected.I hope this clue can help you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In case it interests you, I had the same problem. See my answer. Bounty, anyone?

Comment: While it is not immediately related to the matter, this code will not compile in C. It was apparently compiled by C++ compiler.

Answer (score 4):

I got “Invalid read of size 2” trying to `malloc()` a 2x2 single channel texture (4 bytes / `uint8_t`s). I assumed the allocation was too small - word size on the architecture in question is 8 bytes (64-bit) - so I doubled the allocation and it stopped valgrind's complaints. Since `malloc()` is supposed to be aligned, I was a bit surprised by this (I'm sure it's something that would be obvious to the experts), but maybe it will help someone else. Not obliged to *use* the extra allocated space, it just needs to be there.

...It's a fix even if it doesn't bring insight. Problem occurred on **gcc 4.9.1 (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6).**